# Siri Kit custom intent

Tags: ios, siri, sirikit

Is it possible to perform other actions outside the assumed actions supported by Siri's intents using Siri kit?

And a lot more importantly, even if I could hack and slash my way around using a messaging intent (or some other intent), would it actually be accepted by iTunes store?

Lets say in a scenario, I want my app to support **searching online for something**, or **sending emails** or simply searching through a data base in my app, could I use Siri without that kind of specific intent existing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Siri uses the Intents to format how your phrases and actions are presented to users.
Supported Intents listed [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sirikit).

If your app doesn't fit into the supported Intents you can't create new ones. 
If you app fits the supported Intents [you can define custom vocabulary](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sirikit/registering_custom_vocabulary_with_sirikit) specific to your app.

As for App Review, I think you will have to find who's been through this particular use case or make a small app and submit it to see.
In my experience, reviewers aren't merciless dictators when features are well explained they do let some exceptions in. (a common example is allowing location services to enable background uploading like in google drive and dropbox).

Comment: Just a small addition: even if you add a custom vocabulary, some words are mandatory for most intents, so you cannot create fully custom intent phrases even if the existing Intents fit your goals functionally.

Comment: Update: Things might have change with the release of [custom intents](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/211/) in iOS 12.